# webkit property not working in blackberry 6

Tags: javascript, css, html, blackberry

I tried the following code to give gradient property  (through webkit) to button in my mobile webpage.
Gradient works fine in Iphone & Android, but it is not working in Blackberry 6.0 native browser.

```
<style>
.btnclass
{
height:70px;
width:300px;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #B56D73 20%, #CFDC8E 60%, #F9FFAB 80%);
background-image:linear-gradient(bottom, #B56D73 20%, #CFDC8E 60%, #F9FFAB 80%);
}
</style>

<body>
<form><input type="button" class="btnclass"></form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this [page](http://caniuse.com/css-gradients), CSS Gradients in Blackberry is only available from the version 7. If you want to mimic the same behaviour you will need to have an image with the gradient and apply it in this case (you can use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to detect CSS Gradients).